# How does seemingly variadic function work as in Actix-web and Bevy?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, actix-web, bevy

Ok, I know it is not really a variadic function, but I do not know how to specify it more clearly in the title.

Both Actix-web (`Route::to`) and Bevy (`App::add_system`) have functions which accept a variable number of arguments. I would very much like to know:

- how is this (Rust) design pattern called?
- how does it work? For example, how does Actix-web 'know' that `to` has been passed a function with a `Query` and perhaps a `Path` type?

All I could find out is that the function should implement a type (`Handler<>`/`InfoSystemDescriptor<>`), but in the case of `Handler<>`, only tuples implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is this (Rust) design pattern called?

I don't think there is a special name, but it is using macros (although not necessary, just to reduce repetition) to implement a trait over all functions with N arguments, for example `Handler` in the case of Actix or `InfoSystemDescriptor` in the case of Bevy.

> but in the case of `Handler<>`, only tuples implement it.

No. It is implemented for *functions* (you can see the `Func` generic parameter in each `impl` that has a `Fn(...)` bound), with the generic parameter `Args` set for their argument types as a tuple.

The way they pass information about the function depends on the actual case, but it's usually some sort of trait method. For example, in actix-web, `Args` (the tuple of the parameter types) must implement [`FromRequest`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.FromRequest.html), and this is forwarded using bunch of [blanket implementations](https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.1.0/src/actix_web/extract.rs.html#407-418) to each of the arguments, so eventually each argument gets parsed using its `FromRequest` impl, and that is passed to the function via [`Handler::call()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.Handler.html#tymethod.call). Similarly, the return type is required to implement [`Responder`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.Responder.html).